# Select distinct fields from multiple table

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1 -

```
ID  VehicleID
1    A
2    A
3    A
1    B
1    C
4    C
2    D
```

Table 2-

```
ID  VehicleID VehicleNo
1    A          AA
2    A          AA
3    A
1    B          BB
1    C          CC
4    C          CC
2    D          DD
```

Output-

```
VehicleId  VehicleNo
A            AA
B            BB
C            CC
D            DD
```

Comment: seems `table2` is enough to use in order to return the desired result such as `SELECT DISTINCT VehicleID, VehicleNo FROM table2 WHERE VehicleNo IS NOT NULL`. Since, table1 is just a duplication of the table2 for `ID` and `VehicleID` columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood it; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- calculate "RN" (so that you'd have something to match rows on)
  3  a as
  4    (select vehicleid,
  5       row_number() over (order by vehicleid) rn
  6     from (select distinct vehicleid from tab1)
  7    ),
  8  b as
  9    (select vehicleno,
 10       row_number() over (order by vehicleno) rn
 11     from (select distinct vehicleno from tab2)
 12    )
 13  -- final query
 14  select a.vehicleid, b.vehicleno
 15  from a left join b on a.rn = b.rn;

VEHICLEID  VEHICLENO
---------- ----------
A          AA
B          BB
C          CC
D          DD

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is aggregation:

```
select VehicleId, max(VehicleNo) as VehicleNo
from table2
group by VehicleId;
```